# JSP Servlet HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

This is my first post. I hope someone can help me =)
Usually I'll try to find solutions to this kind of problems on my own.
But this issue is causing me headache ...

With the action tag in the html code below I want to start the java servlet.
Sadly I always get the HTTP 404 - Not found error.
I've already tried to write /Login, ../Login, Login (upper and lower case) and so on.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── ps_18_gruppe09
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── com.food42.servlet
│       │       └── LoginServelet.java
│       WebContent  
│       ├── html
│       │   └── login.jsp
│       └── WEB-INF
│           └── lib
│               └── web.xml
```

I've already tried the solutions answered on similar kind of posts but they sadly didn't help.

In my Java Build Path I've the following Libraries installed:
Apache Tomcat v8.5
JRE System Library[jre1.8.0_201a]
Web App Libraries
MySQL JDBC Driver
EAR Libraries
JUnit5
log4j-1.2.17.jar

Source Folder is ps_18_gruppe09/src/main

Full error message:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /ps_18_gruppe09/Login
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.35

Thanks in advance for your help =)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServletDBLog4j</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <context-param>
    <param-name>dbUser</param-name>
    <param-value>admin</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>dbPassword</param-name>
    <param-value>Food42</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>dbURL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/lib/log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/AppErrorHandler</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/AppErrorHandler</location>
  </error-page>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.food42.servlet.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Food42 Login Page</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link href="../vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Plugin CSS -->
<link href="../vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="../css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav
        class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase"
        id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="startseite.html">Food42</a>
            <button
                class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded"
                type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                Menu <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="topnav">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Suchen...">
            </div>
            <form action="suchresultate.html">
                <input type="submit" value="Suchen" class="searchButton" />
            </form>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a
                        class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger"
                        href="register.html">Registrieren</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center"> </header>

    <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mb-0">Benutzer-Login</h2>
            <hr class="star-dark mb-5">
            <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login" method="post">
                <h3 class="text-center">Bitte geben Sie Ihre Login-Daten ein:</h3>
                <fieldset class="container" style="width: 400px">
                    <table style="width: 400px">
                        <tr>
                            <th><label class="mt-2 mb-2" for="username">Username:</label></th>
                            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"
                                required autofocus /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label class="mt-2 mb-2" for="password">Password:</label></th>
                            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                                required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label class="mt-2 mb-2" for="pwdconfirm">Best&auml;tigen:</label></th>
                            <td><input type="password" id="pwdconfirm" name="pwdconfirm"
                                required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label class="mt-4 mb-3 " for="submit"></label> <input
                                type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase mb-4">Location</h4>
                    <p class="lead mb-0">
                        ZHAW Winterthur <br>Technikum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase mb-4">Around the Web</h4>
                    <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><a
                            class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social text-center rounded-circle"
                            href="https://www.facebook.com/Food42ch-954018978130563/?modal=admin_todo_tour">
                                <i class="fab fa-fw fa-facebook-f"></i>
                        </a></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><a
                            class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social text-center rounded-circle"
                            href="https://twitter.com/Food42C?edit=true"> <i
                                class="fab fa-fw fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><a
                            class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social text-center rounded-circle"
                            href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/food42-ch/"> <i
                                class="fab fa-fw fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase mb-4">Food42</h4>
                    <p class="lead mb-0">Share your food
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <div class="copyright py-4 text-center text-white">
        <div class="container">
            <small>Copyright &copy; Food42 2018</small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button (Only visible on small and extra-small screen sizes) -->
    <div class="scroll-to-top d-lg-none position-fixed ">
        <a class="js-scroll-trigger d-block text-center text-white rounded"
            href="#page-top"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="../js/freelancer.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
package com.food42.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.food42.util.User;

@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/Login"})
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String errorMsg = null;

        if(username == null || username.equals("")){
            errorMsg ="Username can't be null or empty";
        }

        if(password == null || password.equals("")){
            errorMsg = "Password can't be null or empty";
        }

        if(errorMsg != null){
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>"+errorMsg+"</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);
        } else {
        Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select id, title, prename, lastname, dateofbirth, mail, signupdate from user where username=? and password=? limit 1");
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs != null && rs.next()){

                User user = new User(rs.getString("lastName"), rs.getString("preName"), rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("birthDate"), rs.getString("zip"), rs.getString("cityName"), rs.getString("street"), rs.getString("mail"), rs.getString("username"));
                logger.info("User found with details = " + user);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("User", user);
                response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");;
            } else {
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                logger.error("User not found with username = " + username);
                out.println("<font color=red>No user found with given email id, please register first.</font>");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Database connection problem");
            throw new ServletException("Database Connection problem.");
        } 
            finally{
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.error("SQLException in closing PreparedStatement or ResultSet");;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar project I have, I do it this way,

**1** - I don't declare anything in the Servlet class, just have it like that,

```
public class Margin extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

& I make all the Servlet declarations inside my web.xml,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Margin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gr.thebexperts.servlets.Margin</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Margin</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Margin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is probably not related to your issue but you can try it in a similar way.

**2** - What is different though that maybe causes the issue is that you can try to place your login.jsp page at the same level as WEB-INF, meaning directly under /WebContent, it will probably work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Sadly the problem was my directory structure. I've posted the answer just now if you're interested =)

Comment: @ValeriaDR Glad that you found the solution, well done!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.
I'll post the solution maybe it helps someone with a similar kind of problem.

I had to change my project directory structure.
My problem was that i named my java-packages `com.example.test` (in my project `com.food42.servlet`) instead of creating a directory for com and in the com directory a directory named example and so on.

Before:

> ```
> src
> ├── main
> │   ├── com.food42.database
> │   │   └── database.sql
> │   ├── com.food42.servlet
> │   │   ├── AuthenticationFilter.java
> │   │   ├── LoginServlet.java
> │   │   ├── LogoutServlet.java
> │   │   └── RegisterServlet.java
> │   ├── com.food42.servlet.errorhandler
> │   │   └── AppErrorHandler.java
> │   ├── com.food42.servlet.listeners
> │   │   └── AppContextListener.java
> │   └── com.food42.util
> │       ├── DBConnectionManager.java
> │       └── User.java
> └── test
>     └── TestLoginFilter.java
> ```

Afterwards:

> ```
> src
> ├── main
> │   └── java
> │       └── com
> │           └── food42
> │               ├── database
> │               │   └── database.sql
> │               ├── servlet
> │               │   ├── AuthenticationFilter.java
> │               │   ├── LoginServlet.java
> │               │   ├── LogoutServlet.java
> │               │   ├── RegisterServlet.java
> │               │   ├── errorhandler
> │               │   │   └── AppErrorHandler.java
> │               │   └── listeners
> │               │       └── AppContextListener.java
> │               └── util
> │                   ├── DBConnectionManager.java
> │                   └── User.java
> └── test
>     └── TestLoginFilter.java
> ```

Credit to my professor who helped me find out what the problem was =)

Some images to better show my changes:

> [Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAU4u.png)
>   [Deployment_Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6by2.png)
>   [Build_path_source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdgWp.png)
>   [Build_path_libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj3D4.png)